# click on image that image style should change or image should be change in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have 4 images in 2 columns, when I clicked on one image its style should change like color, shadow should change or that image should be replaced by other image. Once click on that image, other images should remain same. It should work like radio buttons. How to do that? Please help me, thanks in advance.

```
final img_rowi= Center(child:
new Container(
  color:   Colors.transparent,

  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),child: Stack(

        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          svgIcon,new GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                pressed = !pressed;
              });

            },
            child:
          Container(

            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(

                  child: new Image.asset(
                    'images/sheep_female.png',
                    height: 50.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  child: new Text('Sheep',style: pressed
                      ? TextStyle(color: const Color(0xFFCDCDCD),fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                   )
                      : TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                   ),),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),),

      Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),child:
      Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          svgIcon,new GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              setState(() {
                pressed1 = !pressed1;
              });

            },
            child:
          Container(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  child: new Image.asset(
                    'images/biily_doe.png',
                    height: 50.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  child: new Text('Billy Doe',style: pressed1
                      ? TextStyle(color: const Color(0xFFCDCDCD),fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  )
                      : TextStyle(color:Colors.black,fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  ),),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),),

    ],
  ),
),

);
```

Comment: Which class are you extending? You need to use StatefulWidget.

Comment: please provide code. am new to flutter

Comment: Which class are you extending from? StatefulWidget or StatelessWidget. Kindly provide proper details.

Comment: am using statefulwidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store initial properties of Image in variables. For example if I want to set initial color of `FlutterLogo` widget to `Colors.blue` then declare a state in the class. Then wrap your Image with `GestureDetector` widget and set `onTap` property. Now call `setState` method and change all the variables (properties of Image) inside it.

Below is an example where there is one `FlutterLogo` widget where I've set initial color of that widget to be `Colors.blue` and when I tap on it, color of `FlutterLogo` widget is changed to `Colors.green`. If I again tap on it and if color is `Colors.green` then it changes color to `Colors.yellow` and so on. You can do similar thing with your Image and change it's size, visibility and other properties.

There is also `imagePath` variable which stores path of initial asset and when user taps on second widget (`Image.asset`) in `Column`, value of variable `imagePath` is changed and `build` method get called again and image is replaced.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool visibility;
  Color colorOfFlutterLogo = Colors.blue;
  String imagePath1 = "assets/initial-path-of-image-1";
  String imagePath2 = "assets/initial-path-of-image-2";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => setState(() {
                    if (colorOfFlutterLogo == Colors.blue)
                      colorOfFlutterLogo = Colors.green;
                    else if (colorOfFlutterLogo == Colors.green)
                      colorOfFlutterLogo = Colors.yellow;
                    else if (colorOfFlutterLogo == Colors.yellow)
                      colorOfFlutterLogo = Colors.blue;
                  }),
              child: FlutterLogo(
                size: double.infinity,
                colors: colorOfFlutterLogo,
              ),
            ),

            // Image 1
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => setState(() {
                    imagePath2 = "assets/new-path-for-image-2";
                  }),
              child: Image.asset(imagePath1),
            ),

            // Image 2
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => setState(() {
                    imagePath1 = "assets/new-path-for-image-1";
                  }),
              child: Image.asset(imagePath2),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: if i click on 2nd image in a row. first image should go back back to previous state. how to do that. like radio button

Comment: I've updated my answer. Wrap second Image with `GestureDetector` and call `setState` on `onTap` which changes path (variable) of first Image. Declare multiple variables to store path of multiple images. You can use List as well.